# Google Form get Google Sheets Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've got a Google Form to enter deposits and withdrawals into a Google Sheet and then the ending balance is calculated so the user can balance their check book.

I'm trying to get the most recent balance to display on the Google Form by finding the last row with a balance that is in the 'Ending Balance' column.

It seems a script may be easiest but nothing seems to so what I need. Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Here's the sheet I have set up, it's connected to my form with the headers in row 2.
[Google Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgm24.jpg)

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Are you familiar with `getLastRow()`? [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: How do you put value from script to google form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can

- create a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) attached to your destination spreadsheet
- set up a [installable trigger `onFormSubmit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that will fire every time a new form is submitted
- access the newest form submission data with [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- Retrieve the values in column 11 (which contains your Ending balance)

*Sample script:*

```
function getMyBalance(){
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var row=sheet.getLastRow();
  var column=11;
  var balance=sheet.getRange(row, column).getValue();
  Logger.log(balance);
}
```